# Get directly an instance from Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I inject `MyObject` in `FirstFragment` by Hilt, This fragment replaces with another fragment, and as well as you know, when one fragment is replaced with another, `onDestroyView()` called and when you press back, the view will be created again.

I need to create a new instance of `MyObject` whenever the fragment's view is created. in [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/) I could get directly an instance inside of my code with `get<MyObject>()` but in Hilt, I couldn't find anything and I have to inject it as a constructor or property.

I also tried to use `ViewWithFragmentComponent` to change my scope, but I get an error when I use this instead of `ApplicationComponent`

How can I have a new instance of `MyObject` whenever my view created in my fragment?

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FirstFragment : BaseFragment(){
    @Inject lateinit var myObject: MyObject
}
```

```
@InstallIn(ViewWithFragmentComponent::class)
@Module
object MyModule{

    @Provides
    internal fun provideMyObject(): MyObject {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @IR42 I've already tried with it

Answer (score 2):

To get instance from hilt directly you should use [EntryPoint](https://dagger.dev/hilt/entry-points.html) annotation:

example code can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-hilt#10

Steps are as follows:

1. Declare in your non-Hilt aware class an interface implementing a method returning interface of instance you want to retrieve from Hilt.
2. Annotate this interface with

   ```
   @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
   @EntryPoint
   ```

assuming your instance is a singleton, so it would look as follows:

```
 class MyAnyKindOfClass {

   @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
   @EntryPoint
   interface MyObjectEntryPoint{
       fun getMyObject(): MyObject;
   }

   fun getMyObject(): MyObject {
     val hiltEntryPoint = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
        appContext, // You need to provid ApplicationContext
        MyObjectEntryPoint::class.java)
     return hiltEntryPoint.getMyObject()
   }
 }
```

Comment: Great answer! At first, it wasn't clear to me how to use it, but after looking at the Google sample, I understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, whenever you inject something into a fragment and this fragment gets destroyed, the injected object gets destroyed as well. So in your example, when `onDestroyView()` is called `myObject` will be garbage collected. Clicking the back button then will trigger `onCreateView()` and dagger-hilt will automatically provide a new instance of `myObject.`

If you always want the same object, you have to annotate it with @Singleton. Optional, you can also use @FragmentScoped, where the documentation says:

> Scope annotation for bindings that should exist for the life of a fragment.

But to my mind, this is not needed as I personally found at that an object provided by dagger-hilt gets recreated when the fragments gets recreated. Using `@FragmentScope` made my life harder as it introduced some other bugs.

You can look [here](https://dagger.dev/hilt/) to learn more about scoping and the functionality of dagger-hilt

Comment: Garbage collected when `onDestroy()` is called not `onDestroyView()`. If you click on the back button, your fragment is restored from the back stack, and `onCreateView()` is called again, without creating a new instance of your fragment.